# Why does '&page' in my Javascript code show up as '&amp;amp;page' in web browser

Tags: javascript, html

This is my script and it's being placed in the header internally on the html document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function l(d){
 var site = '6708', page = 'blahblah', s, er = d.createElement('script');
 er.type = 'text/javascript';
 er.async = true;
 er.src = '//randomsite.com/?site=' + site + '&page=' + page; // **
 s = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 s.parentNode.insertBefore(er, s);
})(document);
</script>
```

and for some reason in Chrome when I check the console it shows up as

```
+ site + '&amp;amp;page='
```

instead of

```
+ site + '&page=' + page;
```

**Edit**

So the error disappeared after clearing up console and browser settings. But now a new error has shown up, and I'm not sure what this means

I'm at a loss as to why that is.
[image: error]

Comment: "it's being placed in the header internally on the html document" - placed by what? Can we see that code? And how do you check it in the console?

Comment: Try changing "&page=" to "&amp;page=". The &amp; should be decoded correctly by chrome.

Comment: @Amadan well I'm using website called Leadpages, and for the analytic section says its in the header and that's where the script is going.

Comment: @Silkster if i do that, wouldn't that affect the javascript code, it's meant for tracking, I think the people that gave it to my boss, who handed it down to me, who knows I don't know JS that well, called it a "pixel". I'm just doing the design but i see that happening and Boss wants me to fix it because devs are not in office.

Comment: I see no reason in your code for the behaviour you describe and it certain works fine for me (Firefox and Chrome). What and how are you displaying in the console?

Comment: @Umeed &amp; is treated like & by chrome. It should be ok. I agree with Álvaro.

Comment: It is more than likely that it is being inserted wrong, either by you entering it into the leadpages UI or by leadpages when inserting it into the page. Consult Leadpages customer support.

Comment: @Silkster ohh i see, thank you for that I had no idea. I'm getting a new issue now though lol. I cleared my cookies, cache, console, all that. And now I'm getting a different error.  `net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIEN` I'll post a picture of it.

Comment: Do you have an ad blocker installed in your browser?

Comment: hi folks, I want to thank you all for your help. Ad blocker was installed on our computers (I wasn't aware of it I only started the day i posted this) as soon as I saw Silkster's message about it I went and investigated and there it was. So I disabled it, now I don't get any issues! lol I feel so stupid, I was only suppose to design the page not deal with any of the analytic stuff, but I learned something from this, so again thank you guys.

Comment: @Silkster if you want to post that ad blocker comment as the solution, I can mark it as the answer and close this embarrassing moment lol

Comment: @Umeed, not sure if you can change the solution, but I added mine below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have an ad blocker installed in your browser. Disable it and try again. ;-)

Comment: thanks Silkster, I'm not sure why Simon's was selected as the answer, i might have done that by mistake. But yes this did solve my problem to whomever downvoted it, so i upvoted lol

Answer (score 1):

You should be getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token *  with the ** before site and after page.  How have you embedded it in the html? this seemed to work fine for me:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function l(d){
 var site = '6708', page = 'blahblah', s, er = d.createElement('script');
 er.type = 'text/javascript';
 er.async = true;
 er.src = '//randomsite.com/?site=' + site + '&page=' + page;
 s = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 s.parentNode.insertBefore(er, s);
})(document);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: originally it was embedded into the body by someone else, i guess thats why i had the error, i moved it to the header, and its gone now but a new error shows up from a different script that's also in the header. I posted a screen shot of the error

Comment: @Umeed JavaScript tracking codes should be moved to bottom of `<body>` as in the answer so they don't block loading of other elements (but apart from performance it shouldn't make a difference, since the code you've shared does work in either places)